# Google sheets API SSLEOFError (_ssl.c:2396)

Tags: python, ssl, google-sheets-api, eof

`SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)`

I get this error while trying to upload some web-scraped data to my google sheet, its not any more than Ive uploaded at once before, nor did I hit the end of the sheet. the data itself seems to be fine.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']


SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = path+r'\keys.JSON'
creds= None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes = SCOPES)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()
sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=WKBKID, range=f'SheetName!A1', valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body={'values':[[data1],[data2],[data3],[etc]]}).execute()
```

if I start debugging before the last line runs and run it from the debug console it uploads like normal, but still gives the error when the program tries? help?

Comment: I'm unable to fully reproduce the exact error when attempting on my end (it works without any error on my end). Perhaps, there's something more in your setup that is not included in your question. However, I think it would be better if you could report the issue _(if it is really consistent)_ on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) & provide necessary details to fully reproduce the error. See [this quite similar report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242134769) submitted on the issue tracker about the same error but on `Gmail API`.

Comment: awesome thankyou, I got around the error by using a while True: try loop, so it just keeps trying until it does it correctly. not exactly elegant but it worked